# Java Coordinates Calculation

Tags: java, algorithm, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

may I know if there is an existing algorithm or ways to calculate this scenario? Initially, there are 2 coordinates given, x1y1 and x2y2 and we draw a straight line between them.

When we are given the third coordinates x3y3, i would like to know if this third coordinate are within a certain distance from the straight line.

[image]

Comment: most likely there is, yes.

Comment: Is the region of interest what you show in the drawing? Because in principle you could also take the two semicircles at each end of the segment. In any case, especially if you are going to do a lot of these tests, you can just construct the inner rectangle and check if the point is inside it (and if you need the semicircles check distance to each end).

Comment: Figure out how to do the math on paper, then translate to a programming language.

Comment: This technically a request for a tool, so it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert the math here to code, but this should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

[image]